# Can I trigger Math AutoCorrect in Word 2007 without moving the cursor?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, cursor, autocorrect

I use Math AutoCorrect in Word 2007, including in body text.  I have "Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions" checked in the AutoCorrect Options.  Is there any way to trigger the AutoCorrect without moving the cursor?

*Use case:* I am trying to type, e.g., `50±10%`.  If I key in `50\pm5%` and hit Space, nothing happens.  To get the `±` I have to type `50\pm<space><backspace>5%`.  The `backspace` is to get rid of the space that triggered the AutoComplete of `\pm`.
Likewise, if I hit `Enter` instead of `space`, the cursor moves to the next line.  I am trying to not have to backspace over the added whitespace.

I tried hitting F3, using `TypeText` in a VBA macro, and inserting a zero-width nonbreaking space; none triggered AutoComplete.  I also searched Google and MSDN, including the `OMathAutoCorrect` object, with no luck.

I can think of two options, neither of which I like.

1. Use Autohotkey to send `<space><backspace>`.  I don't use AHK for anything else and would like to avoid having yet another process running if possible.
2. Search the `OMathAutoCorrect.Entries` collection and hand-replace.  I am concerned about speed, though.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: `50\pm5%` is nonsensical even in a math context and won't ever trigger the replacement. You can use `+-` if you want `±`, though (which is replaced immediately because it's not alphanumeric). In any case, your example would need proper spacing anyway which would render the issue non-existent as well.

Comment: @Joey - I appreciate the suggestion about `+-`.  That will be very helpful.  This issue is not nonsensical to me, and what I am typing does not need any spacing in my particular context.  I'm coming from TeX, in which `50\pm5\%` would do the Right Thing without any whitespace from me (since `5` is not a valid identifier character).  I am hoping Word can do something similar.

Comment: Well, Word has other rules than TeX. One major difference is tokenizing. While `x^21` would yield *x* ² 1 in TeX it yields *x* ²¹ in Word. TeX tokenises by character, macro or block with braces; Word makes that distinction with whitespace. It may sound a little insane, but I found it to be much more useful in practice. http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/ has a description of the format. I would think it's considered to be easy to write, not easy to golf ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out `OMathAutoCorrect.Entries` will index by the text you enter, so you can look up items quickly.  I wrote the following macro and assigned ito to a keyboard shortcut.  Here it is in case it helps anyone else!

```
Public Sub ConvertMathAutoCorrectEntryStartingWithBackslash()
' Convert an autocorrect entry beginning with a backslash, and don't move the cursor.
    Dim st As Long, en As Long
    Dim needle As String
    Dim fontname As String

    ' Find the text to replace
    st = Selection.Start
    en = Selection.End
    If st = en Then
        'Nothing selected.  Assume we're at the end of a just-typed abbreviation.
        Selection.MoveStartUntil "\", wdBackward    'leaves the cursor just before the \
        Selection.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1         'grab the \, too
    End If
    needle = Selection.Text
    fontname = Selection.Characters(1).Font.Name

    ' Find the replacement
    Dim entry As OMathAutoCorrectEntry

    Set entry = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set entry = Application.OMathAutoCorrect.entries.Item(needle)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not (entry Is Nothing) Then
        ' A match - make the replacement
        Selection.Delete
        Selection.InsertAfter entry.Value
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Selection.Font.Name = fontname  ' So the font doesn't carry over from the math
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' We didn't find it - put the cursor back
    Selection.Start = st
    Selection.End = en
End Sub 'ConvertMathAutoCorrectEntryStartingWithBackslash
```